# Oracle SQL query workout days between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g, oracle10g

I require assistance with a SQL query that will produce the days of week between Start_date and End_Date and using the weekday.

**Example**:
between start and End date for Calendar 99 required is the date for Weekday "Wednesday" starting point (seqnum 1) and Weekday  Saturday (seqnum2).

*In a nutshell* Day of week dates between 2 dates depending on calendar and weekdays and seqnum for order in which to be produced.

Any help or ideas would be highly appreciated.

[image: Sample Calendar Table]

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR
(
  CALENDAR_NAME  VARCHAR2(500 CHAR),
  START_DATE     VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  END_DATE       VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
  SEQNUM         NUMBER,
  WEEKDAY        VARCHAR2(9 CHAR),
  STARTTIME      VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
);

Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('99', '2020-07-29', '2021-08-07', 1, 'WEDNESDAY', 
    '17:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('99', '2020-07-29', '2021-08-07', 2, 'SATURDAY', 
    '17:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('179', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 1, 'MONDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDARR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('179', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 2, 'WEDNESDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('179', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 3, 'FRIDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('179', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 4, 'SUNDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 1, 'TUESDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 2, 'WEDNESDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 3, 'THURSDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 4, 'FRIDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 5, 'SATURDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 6, 'SUNDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
Insert into CALENDAR
   (CALENDAR_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE, SEQNUM, WEEKDAY, 
    STARTTIME)
 Values
   ('772', '2000-01-02', '2021-02-01', 7, 'MONDAY', 
    '18:00:00');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I don't understand what is required from the input data. (Not my fault - you are not explaining it clearly.) Perhaps if you post the desired output that will help. How many columns are in the output? What are they? (I assume at least the "calendar" and the "seqnum" must appear in the output; what else?) For columns that only appear in the output, but not in the intput - what do they represent? Let's take the first sample row from your data. What do you need in the output? ALL the Wednesdays between start and end? A **count** of those days? Just the first Wednesday? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a nutshell Day of week dates between 2 dates depending on calendar and weekdays and seqnum for order in which to be produced.

If this is to be interpreted as, for each `calendar_name`, you want to start from the `start_date` and output the day of the week that matches `weekday` for each week until you get to the `end_date`.

*Note: It would be better if stored the dates in a date data type.*

You can use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH dates (calendar_name, dt, end_date) AS (
  SELECT calendar_name,
         NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - INTERVAL '1' DAY, weekday),
         TO_DATE(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  FROM   calendar
  WHERE  NEXT_DAY(TO_DATE(start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') - INTERVAL '1' DAY, weekday)
           <= TO_DATE(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
UNION ALL
  SELECT calendar_name,
         dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY,
         end_date
  FROM   dates
  WHERE  dt + INTERVAL '7' DAY <= end_date
)
SELECT calendar_name,
       dt
FROM   dates
ORDER BY
       calendar_name,
       dt
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=219b40e7ab16ff30ecfcac374edff3d1)*